# Floating action button badge

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Каким образом можно разместить над fab бейдж с циферкой: например, количество непрочитанных или новых уведомлений.

Использую Floating Action Button (`android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`).

Эта кнопка открывает сообщения, хочу чтобы сверху FAB было количество непрочитанных сообщений. Нашёл что такие цифры называются бэйдж.

Как реализовать отображение бэйджа не знаю, прошу совета.

Вот как оно выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На самом деле сделать это самому не так уж сложно, можете посмотреть как реализовано в [этом проекте](https://github.com/jcxavier/badge-button) - Расширяем класс `FrameLayout` и помещаем туда два виджета.  Есть [готовая библиотека Android ViewBadger](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger), которая позволяет прицепить бэйдж к любому `View` - если не хочется заморачиваться, лучший вариант. Ну и на GitHub как всегда [можно найти массу вариантов](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=badge+android&type=Repositories) реализации.

Comment: Писать сюда реализацию в качестве ответа нет смысла, так как решение включает ресурсы, изображения и тп.,  а не только код.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать отдельный view над вашим float action button или же вы можете создать своего наследника float action button. Или же можете использовать эту либу https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Comment: создать отдельный view над вашим float action button - это тоже далеконе тривиальный квест,
наследоваться от fab? хорошо. а что дальше делать я не представляю
использовать эту либу да, но она не предоставляет функционала badge
The API is extremely limited at the moment. It solves few select use cases in the app I'm working on.